# Powershell - Parse outlook for folder buried two levels down

Tags: powershell, outlook

Inbox

....|___Folder1

.............|___Folder2

I have the code to search a folder under inbox but I'm having trouble understanding how to search for certain fields for folders under a folder.  I need to do some sort of recursion?

```
$olFolderInbox = 6
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application;
$ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI");
$inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)

$Folder1 = $inbox.Folders | where-object { $_.name -eq "Folder1" }      
$Folder1Mail = $UTSFolder.items | Select-Object -Property Subject, ReceivedTime, Body
```

I can then use an input.txt for a list of info I'm looking for and compare it to each item from that inbox.

```
$Inputs = Get-Content input.txt

Foreach ($Input in $Inputs){
    Foreach ($Mail in $Folder1Mail){
        if ($Mail.Body -like "*$Input*") { 
            Write-Host "Match found!" 
        }
    }
}
```

I found a script that will crawl and list out all folders and subfolders but it's not so clear cut as how to reference them. 
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/b1295e6f-6d16-4df4-b644-f3c7e4031a69

Currently reading Windows PowerShell In Action since I'm sick of just Frankenstein chop-shopping scripts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `MAPIFolder.Folders` collection: VB style:

```
set Folder = inbox.Folders.Item("folder1").Folder.Item("Folder2")
```

Comment: Thanks for tip!  Sorry for late reply